# Access columns of a dataframe based on column names using a 'for' loop

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have data frame consisting of column names `M1out1`, `M1out2`, ..., `M1out120`, `0`, `1`, ..., `120`.

Is there a way in which I can access the columns based on these names using a `for` loop?

Like `for i in range(M1out1, M1out120, 1)` , for columns `M1out1` through `M1out120`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a slice of the dataframe by a range of columns, and get the list of columns names for that slice:

```
for col in df.loc[:, 'M1out0':'M1out15'].columns:
    print(col)
```

Output:

```
M1out0
M1out1
M1out2
M1out3
M1out4
M1out5
M1out6
M1out7
M1out8
M1out9
M1out10
M1out11
M1out12
M1out13
M1out14
M1out15
```

#### Convenience function

```
def col_range(df, start=None, stop=None, step=None):
    return df.loc[:, start:stop:step].columns
```

Usage:

```
# Loop over every 3rd column starting from M1out0 and ending with M1out20:
for col in col_range(df, 'M1out0', 'M1out20', 3):
    print(col)
```

Output:

```
M1out0
M1out3
M1out6
M1out9
M1out12
M1out15
M1out18
```